# Wordpress Custom Query Posts Showposts number

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is a script that I'm still unsure on how to get it to work, in Wordpress I have a repeater field that I can input the number of days that are in a month, so it creates calendar squares for me to highlight in a booking process.

What I want to do, is to have the field 'how_many_days' to run a loop that will then repeat the number of divs calendarPost. So Ideally I can input separate number of loops.

A live version of the output is here: http://universitycompare.com/school-bookings/

```
<?php if(get_field('calendar_repeater_field')): ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('calendar_repeater_field')): ?>
        <?php $numberoffields = get_sub_field('how_many_days'); ?>

        <?php $wp_query->query('showposts='.$numberoffields ); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="calendarPost">
            <span class="title"><?php the_sub_field('calendar_month_name'); ?><span class="circleOpen"></span></span>

        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

FYI - I didn't know whether this would be a PHP related problem or WP only, so please advise if it this post should be elsewhere and I will remove and repost in the correct stackoverflow forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't completly explain if you were in fact trying to output posts so below is a couple of suggesstions.

I'll start with what I think you're trying to do:

If you're' just wanting to output the div.calendarPost over and over (based on the number of days) then you don't need a WordPress loop for that. A standard PHP for loop will do

```
<?php if ( get_field('calendar_repeater_field' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( has_sub_field('calendar_repeater_field' ) ) : ?>
        <?php $numberoffields = get_sub_field('how_many_days'); ?>
        <?php for ( $i=0; $i < $numberoffields; $i++ ) { ?>
            <div class="calendarPost">
                <span class="title"><?php the_sub_field('calendar_month_name'); ?><span class="circleOpen"></span></span>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If however you're wanting to output posts (based on the number of days in the ACF field) then you would use the below code.

```
<?php if ( get_field('calendar_repeater_field' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( has_sub_field('calendar_repeater_field' ) ) : ?>
        <?php $numberoffields = get_sub_field('how_many_days'); ?>
        <?php $calendar_posts = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=' . $numberoffields); ?>
        <?php if ( $calendar_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $calendar_posts->have_posts() ) : $calendar_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="calendarPost">
                <span class="title"><?php the_sub_field('calendar_month_name'); ?><span class="circleOpen"></span></span>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Refer to "The Usage" section of the WP Codex for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Scott L Thank you very much, and my apologies for not making my question clear, indeed it was your second answer I was trying to do. I couldn't establish how to should be represented with the WP_Query. Was a difficult work around which I now, understand. Much appreciated.

Comment: @OwenO'Neill no problem, glad it solved your issue. Also note that when you're inside the WP_Query you're accessing the data associated to the post so where you have the_sub_field('calendar_month_name') it won't work. You need to retrieve data that is associated with the post, like the_title() or an ACF field assigned to that post.